# Download Debian - Configure the Network Problem

Tags: debian, network-interface

I was downloading and installing debian to make it my main OS. And i'm stuck somewhere.

My first question :

Debian gets stuck on "Configure the Network" while installing. I am using laptop and ASUS USB-N14 Wireless-N300

first display:

```
Attemption to find an available wireless network failed.

"X" is a wireless network interface. Please enter the name (the ESSID) of the wireless network you would like "X" to use. To connect to any available network, leave thıs field blank.

Wireless ESSID for "X":
....................
```

Second display

```
Choose WEP/Open if the network is open or secured with WEP. Choose WPA/WPA2 if the network is protect with WPA/WPA2 PSK(Pre-Shared Key).

Wireless network type for "X":
...............................
```

Third display

```
Enter the passphrase for WPA/WPA2 PSK authentication. This should be the passphrase defined for the wireless network you are trying to use.

WPA/WPA2 passphrase for wireless device "X":
...............................
```

I enter the correct information and press continue, but after the third screen it sends me back to the first screen.

My Second Question:

When installing the Windows 10 operating system with usb, there were options such as format and delete.There were no such options when installing the debian. How can I install debian after completely cleaning the SSD?

Comment: Don't clean SSD's as it is not good for them. Create/delete partitions and format with new file-systems. When you boot Debian

Comment: Drivers for ethernet are much more widely available, so if this is possible you would be much more likely to be able to download suitable wifi software when you have a full install.

Answer (score 1):

Killing IPV6 DHCP config processes works on Debian 12.

Steps:

- Change to a terminal by hitting `Ctrl-F2`
- Get a list of processes with `ps`
- Find any dhclient6 processes and note the process id in second-from-left column.
- Use `kill <process id>` to stop the dhcp 6 processes.
- Return to the graphical installer with `Ctrl-F5`

with thanks for the ipv6 hint [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/g9qv46/comment/j3euu66/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue with Debian 11.3 and installation via an ethernet cable doesn't solve the problem. As a temporary work around download Debian from non-net install image and then resolve the network issue after you have installed the OS.

```
debian-live-11.3.0-amd64.iso
debian-live-11.3.0-amd64+nonfree.iso
```

instead of

```
debian-11.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

Escape to the Debian Installer Main Menu with ESC to avoid the network step. My working suspicion is a corrupted installation medium.

Edit-1: For me it was a corrupted USB.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `debian-live.iso` witch is expressed in [@Winryr01 answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705001/235261) you can download firmwares from [this](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/current/) location and place it in another usb memory then insert it while installing Debian. I think Installing firmware will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Debian installer main menu]

In my case I was able to **skip - Configuring the Network process** by Clicking "**Go Back**" (bottom right button) and accessing Debian installer main menu **steps list** and from there **choosing the next step**. The same worked also to **skip "Configuring the Clock"** step.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).